# How to create heroku based Sinatra apps

Tags: ruby, sinatra, heroku

I am trying to create Sinatra based heroku app without any luck?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To answer your question: Yes!

For reference: http://docs.heroku.com/rack#sinatra

Answer (score 1):

The sinatra application should be as you always do but on the root of your application you should include a config file named **config.ru**

It basically says:

> require 'application' run
>
> Sinatra::Application

Answer (score 0):

There is a new, slightly different procedure for deploying Sinatra (and other Ruby) apps on Heroku/Cedar which involves "foreman" (and a Procfile)... see getting started guide for Ruby:

http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby